# How to add dropdown button into Csv file during exportation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastercsv

I need to Add dropdown button for each row in csv export file i am using Fastercsv gem for csv exportation and my code is

```
 csv_string = FasterCSV.generate({:col_sep => "\t"}) do |csv|
      csv << ["admission_no","first_name","last_name","dob"]
 end
 send_data(csv_string, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :filename => "sample.csv")
```

I need to add or include the drop down button in the above array and that should have some options to select,i mean i want the dropdown button option in csv file itself the drop down should come in each row in csv file this is what i need to achieve so can any one help me out

Comment: The question isn't exact to me. Do you want a dropdown on the html page to select the fields that should be included in the csv file or do you want to implement some excel functionality in the csv itself?

Comment: i want excel functionality in csv file itself i mean drop down in csv file.

Comment: This cant work because csv doenst provide this functionallity. You can do it the way zwippie told you.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is nothing more than a bunch of data entries separated by some character and line breaks. There is **no way** to create dropdowns in a CSV file.

If you want to add Excel functionality, create an `.xslx` file, not a `.csv` file. Perhaps with the help of a gem like [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx). *(Disclaimer: I haver never used that gem myself).*